# Phonegap Android Analytics plugin calling method error

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, analytics

I'm trying to add the analytics plugin to my phonegap (2.0) project. I have it working fine in iOS but in Android, I followed the instructions from the following link but it end with this error:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/uqYjTmd4w_E/JbKNgAQbQpUJ

Everytime I try to run the app in the simulator, I got the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined at file...**

Is someone got the same error?

Thanks

Comment: can you post some of your code?